Bytes validation error while transferring ERC20 tokens while using ethereumjs/tx
I am trying to send an ERC20 token using ethereumjs, but I am getting a bytes validation error:
Web3ValidatorError: Web3 validator found 1 error[s]:
value "0x2,248,191,131,170,54,167,20,138,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,138,50,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,131,1,134,160,148,69,107,234,75,230,106,30,153,131,17,135,224,82,187,35,204,80,76,60,225,128,184,68,169,5,156,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,241,238,52,126,93,180,219,205,26,211,198,173,53,86,135,97,41,239,21,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,192,128,160,211,207,218,109,71,160,105,103,166,53,249,71,106,102,227,176,14,254,66,120,191,187,3,169,82,239,111,66,104,57,197,42,160,83,234,223,102,194,94,169,161,93,202,26,67,91,82,179,8,201,43,191,216,203,161,138,112,243,153,167,67,28,98,140,16" at "/0" must pass "bytes" validation

The function to transfer tokens is below:
async function sendToken(toAddress, amount) {
    const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress);
    const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Sepolia });

    const maxFeePerGas = web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('2', 'gwei'));
    const maxPriorityFeePerGas = web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei')); 

    const txData = {
        "chainId": common.chainId(),
        "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        "maxFeePerGas": maxFeePerGas,
        "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(100000),
        "to": tokenAddress,
        "value": '0x0',  // Should be '0x0' since we are transferring tokens
        "data": tokenContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, BigInt(amount)).encodeABI()
    };


    const encodedData = tokenContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, BigInt(amount)).encodeABI();
    console.log("Encoded Data: ", encodedData);
    console.log("Transaction Data: ", txData);

    try {
        const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(txData, { common: common });
        const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey);
        const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
        const rawTx = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');
        
        console.error('***************');
        console.log('Raw transaction', rawTx);
        console.error('***************');
        
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx);

        console.log(`Transaction Hash: ${receipt.transactionHash}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating or sending transaction:", error);
    }
}

Following is the result of logs:
Encoded Data:  0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000f1ee347e5db4dbcd1ad3c6ad3556876129ef150f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004

Transaction Data:  {
  chainId: 11155111n,
  nonce: '0x14',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '0x31303030303030303030',
  maxFeePerGas: '0x32303030303030303030',
  gasLimit: '0x186a0',
  to: '0x456Bea4bE66a1E99831187e052BB23cc504C3cE1',
  value: '0x0',
  data: '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000f1ee347e5db4dbcd1ad3c6ad3556876129ef150f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004'
}

Raw Transaction : 0x2,248,191,131,170,54,167,20,138,49,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,138,50,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,48,131,1,134,160,148,69,107,234,75,230,106,30,153,131,17,135,224,82,187,35,204,80,76,60,225,128,184,68,169,5,156,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,241,238,52,126,93,180,219,205,26,211,198,173,53,86,135,97,41,239,21,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,192,128,160,211,207,218,109,71,160,105,103,166,53,249,71,106,102,227,176,14,254,66,120,191,187,3,169,82,239,111,66,104,57,197,42,160,83,234,223,102,194,94,169,161,93,202,26,67,91,82,179,8,201,43,191,216,203,161,138,112,243,153,167,67,28,98,140,16


The error comes when it reaches web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx);

The raw transaction should be a hex value, you can generate it from the serializedTx using web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx).
So, replace this line:
const rawTx = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex');

With:
const rawTx = web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);

You need to add the from field in your txData. Also, you're using the hardcoded values for gasLimit, maxPriorityFeePerGas and maxFeePerGas, which might result in the failure of the transaction. So, it's recommended to calculate these values and then append the same into the txData, like:
const txData = {
    chainId: common.chainId(),
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    from: accountAddress,
    to: tokenAddress,
    value: '0x0',  // Should be '0x0' since we are transferring tokens
    data: tokenContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, BigInt(amount)).encodeABI()
};

// Estimate gas limit
const gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas(txData)

txData.gasLimit = gasLimit;

// Get maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas
const { maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas } = await web3.eth.calculateFeeData();

txData.maxPriorityFeePerGas = maxPriorityFeePerGas;
txData.maxFeePerGas = maxFeePerGas;

Here's the full revised code for your sendToken() function:
async function sendToken(toAddress, amount) {
    const txCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress);
    const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Sepolia })

    const txData = {
        chainId: common.chainId(),
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        from: accountAddress,
        to: tokenAddress,
        value: '0x0',  // Should be '0x0' since we are transferring tokens
        data: tokenContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, BigInt(amount)).encodeABI()
    };

    // Estimate gas limit
    const gasLimit = await web3.eth.estimateGas(txData)

    txData.gasLimit = gasLimit;

    // Get maxFeePerGas and maxPriorityFeePerGas
    const { maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas } = await web3.eth.calculateFeeData();

    txData.maxPriorityFeePerGas = maxPriorityFeePerGas;
    txData.maxFeePerGas = maxFeePerGas;

    try {
        const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(txData, { common: common });
        const signedTx = tx.sign(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

        // Serialize signedTx to Uint8Array
        const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();

        // Convert Uint8Array to Hex
        const rawTx = web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);

        console.error('***************');
        console.log('Raw transaction:', rawTx);
        console.error('***************');

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx)
            .on('transactionHash', function (hash) {
                console.log('transactionHash:', hash);
            })
            .on('receipt', function (receipt) {
                console.log('receipt:', receipt);
            })
            .on('error', function (error, receipt) {
                console.log(error, receipt);
            });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating or sending transaction:", error);
    }
}

